# What is the sum of all possible values of $\gamma$

Tags: polynomials

> The polynomial $x^3 +ax^2 +bx+c$ has three roots $\alpha ≤ \beta ≤ \gamma$, all of which are positive integers. Given that $2^2(a) + 2^1(b) + 2^0(c) = −2^{11}$ what is the sum of all possible values of $γ$?

I tried using Vieta's and finding some relations there such as $-a = \alpha+\beta + \gamma$, to get that $2^2(a) + 2^1(b) + 2^0(c) = -4(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)+2(\alpha \beta +\alpha \gamma + \beta \gamma) -\alpha \beta \gamma = -2^{11}$ but that didn't help me.

Comment: I think you should try all combinations where $2^2.a+2^1.b=0$ and noticing your condition i think c should be $2^{-13}$

Comment: @ArchisWelankar:  as the roots are positive integers and $c$ is the negative product of the roots, it must be a negative integer

Answer (score 1):

Let $p(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c$. Then
$$ p(2) = 2^3 + 2^2a+2b+c = 2^3 - 2^{11}. $$
On the other hand, since $p(x) = (x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)$, it follows that
$$ (2-\alpha)(2-\beta)(2-\gamma) = 2^3 - 2^{11}. $$
Since the right-hand side is negative, either one or three of the terms in the left-hand side must be negative.

Suppose only one term is negative. Then this term must be $2-\gamma$, as $2-\gamma\le 2-\beta\le 2-\alpha$. Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are positive integers, the only way $2-\alpha>0$ and $2-\beta >0$ is if $\alpha = \beta = 1$. This implies that $2 - \gamma = 2^3 - 2^{11}$, so $\gamma = 2^{11} - 2^3 + 2$ is one possibility.

If all three terms are negative, then take advantage of the fact that all three terms must be negative, and factor the right-hand side. For ease, rewrite the equation as
$$ (\alpha-2)(\beta-2)(\gamma-2) = 2^{11}-2^3 = 2040. $$
Note that $\gamma-2\ge\beta-2\ge\alpha-2$, so we are looking for three positive factors of $2040$, with $\gamma-2$ being the greatest of those three. Now
$$ 2^{11}-2^3 = 2^3(2^8-1) = 2^3(2^4-1)(2^4+1) = 2^3(2^2-1)(2^2+1)(2^4+1) = 2^3\times 3\times 5\times 17.$$
There are $(3+1)\times(1+1)\times(1+1)\times(1+1) = 32$ factors of $2040$, so it's now just a matter of figuring out which of these factors can be equal to $\gamma-2$ for some $\gamma$. Since $\gamma-2$ has to be the largest factor, we must have that $\gamma-2\ge 17$. Otherwise, one of the other two factors will be divisible by $17$, and hence larger than $\gamma-2$, contradiction. So $\gamma-2$ cannot be some factor less than $17$.

I now claim that $\gamma-2$ can be any factor greater than or equal to $17$. To do this, we construct values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to make it work. Let $n = \gamma-2$. Construct $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as follows:

- If $17$ does not divide $n$, then let $\beta - 2 = 17$, and let $\alpha - 2 = \frac{2040}{17n} = \frac{120}{n}$. Since $n\ge 17$, we have $\beta\le\gamma$, and $\alpha-2\le\frac{120}{17}<17 = \beta-2\implies\alpha\le\beta$. We've thus found $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ with $\alpha\le\beta\le\gamma$ and $\gamma -2 = n$, where $n\ge 17$ divides $2040$, but $17$ does not divide $n$, so $\gamma = 2+n$ is a possible value.
- Otherwise, suppose $17$ divides $n$. Note that $\frac{2040}{17} = 120$. It follows that $\frac{2040}{n}$ must divide $120$. Now, we can find two factors of $120$ which multiply to $120$ and are both less than $17$ (namely, $8$ and $15$). Since $\frac{2040}{n}$ divides $120$, we can find two factors less than $17$ which multiply to $\frac{2040}{n}$. Set $\alpha-2$ and $\beta-2$ equal to those two factors (set $\alpha-2$ to be the lower of the two). Then you can easily see that $\alpha\le\beta\le\gamma$, so $\gamma = 2+n$ is a possible value as well.

So, if you take all of the factors of $2040$ greater than or equal to $17$, and add $2$ to them, and add them all up, you get your desired answer. Note that the answer from the first part, when only one term is negative, i.e. $\gamma = 2^{11}-2^3+2$, also comes out of this method, so there is no need to add the two parts.

(If you're looking for an easier way to add all of these factors, note that you are adding $2+$ every factor of $2040$ that is at least $17$. This means that you are not considering the factors $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$, $8$, $10$, $12$, and $15$. So if you know a formula for the sum of the divisors of a given number, then you can just apply the sum and subtract appropriately.)

Comment: So the answer is going to be less than $2000$?

Comment: @Puzzled417 $2^{11} - 2^3 + 2 = 2048 - 8 + 2$.

Comment: I mean the answer to this question because the answer to this question is over $6000$.

Comment: What is the answer to this question?

Comment: @Puzzled417 which part of the question are you still stuck on? I'm willing to help you on another step if you're stuck there, but I won't just tell you the answer...

Comment: I get the first thing you said how $\gamma = 2^{11}-2^3+2$. As for the second part though I get a few possibilities. We could have $2-\gamma = 2^3-2^{11}$, $2-\gamma = -(2^8-1)$, $2-\gamma = -2^4-1$, etc.?

Comment: @Puzzled417 yes, there are quite a few possibilities, such as the ones you mention. You just have to find all such possibilities. One thing to keep in mind is that since $\gamma$ is the greatest root, we want $2-\gamma$ to be the least factor, which means it should be the most negative factor. This limits a few possibilities. For example, we can't have $2-\gamma = -1$, since there's no way for $2-\alpha$ and $2-\beta$ to be both negative and not less than $-1$, while simultaneously having the product be $2^3-2^{11}$.

Comment: Maybe a better way to look at the second case is to say instead that $(\alpha-2)(\beta-2)(\gamma-2) = 2^{11}-2^3$, and to look for all possible values of $\gamma$ given the condition that $\gamma-2$ is the *greatest* term in the left-hand side.

Comment: There are $4$ cases: either $\gamma -2$ is greatest, $\beta -2$ is, $\alpha - 2$ is, or they are all equal. We can get rid of the third case since it is not possible. Then I am trying to see how to relate this to the sum of the divisors of $2040$.

Comment: Do you know how?

Comment: @Puzzled417 Actually, we must have that $\gamma-2$ is the greatest. I've edited the answer above to include more details.